# Do any linux systems depend on at (atd) for system functionality? I want to disable it

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, at

I have a cubieboard (an SBC, like a raspberry pi) that I'm using in an embedded application.  While testing a box before shipping I noted unacceptable lag in the user interface.  Investigation turned up empty files in `/var/spool/cron/atjobs`, which `at` responded to by spamming `rsyslog` 200 times/sec that the file was formatted incorrectly and it was aborting.  On this little ARM processor that was enough to degrade performance immensely.

I don't know what caused these zero byte files to be in the `atjobs` directory, which is extremely frustrating.  My approach to this problem is, by default, to disable `atd` completely.  What I want to know is whether anyone can think of a system usage of `at` that I might be disabling with this course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike cron, which schedules jobs that are repeated periodically,
`at/atd` runs a job at a specific time once.
As far as I know, this isn't used by core Linux and can be uninstalled.

You may see the article
[Managing Linux Services](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/managing-linux-services/)
from 2018 on how to uninstall it using `systemctl` in CentOS.

The article
[Can you kill it? Ubuntu Server startup processes](https://peteris.rocks/blog/can-you-kill-it/#usr-sbin-atd-f)
from 2016 also lists it as a process that can be uninstalled in Ubuntu and
shows how with using `apt`.

The article
[I want to uninstall atd (the "at" daemon)](http://www.davekb.com/browse_computer_tips:fedora_disable_atd_lsb:txt)
from 2012 about RedHat/Fedora/CentOS, notes that it is part of the
LSB (Linux Standard Base), so it gets re-installed every time that `redhat-lsb`
is updated.

My conclusion is that core Linux does not depend on it, but it might be hard to
eradicate permanently.